# Out of memory error in quarkus hibernate panache

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

I am using quarkus with hibernate panache.. My entity has almost 105 attributes. I am following Panache Repository model. To retrieve values from database I have used list(query, param). I do have an "in" case on my query which has max 10 values. What I observed here is after executing the query the memory is not getting free, query process time heap memory also increased and it stayed there.. After 3rd or 4th request it end up in out of memory error. Please help

Adding more details to it.

```
LogManager error of type CLOSE_FAILURE: Error closing resource
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at java.base/java.io.FileDescriptor.close0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileDescriptor.close(FileDescriptor.java:297)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream$1.close(FileOutputStream.java:398)
    at java.base/java.io.FileDescriptor.closeAll(FileDescriptor.java:355)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:396)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:188)
```

This issue is not reproducible in Dev environment , and it is deployed in open shift cloud there I can the see the memory increase in Grafana.

Comment: Can you share an example or a reproducer?, this might be something that you are doing that is not closing the sessions or something like that

Comment: We either need a reproducer (i.e. a simple Maven project reproducing your issue, you can share it on GitHub for instance) and/or a heap dump to understand where the memory is going. If we have a reproducer, we can do the heap dump ourselves.

Comment: The issue is specific to the application, there was a request which fetches a huge number of records and caused the hike in memory. In Grafana it shows as it occupies that memory even after the request processed. But this hike is happens only till half of the max memory reaches. After that it is free up the memory.